# jQuery bind to multiple elements

Tags: jquery, bind

I've got:

```
<div class='someclass'>Text</div>
<div class='otherclass'>Other Text</div>
<style>
    .someclass{
        width:400px;
        height:200px;
    }
    .otherclass{
        width:400px;
        height:200px;
        display:none;
    }
</style>

$('.someclass').mouseover(function(){
    $('.otherclass').fadeIn();
});
$('.someclass).mouseout(function(){
    $('.otherclass').fadeOut();
});
```

But I dont want second div to fade out if the cursor goes over this second div.

I can use

```
$('.someclass,.otherclass').mouseover(function(){
    $('.otherclass').fadeIn();
});
$('.someclass,.otherclass').mouseout(function(){
    $('.otherclass').fadeOut();
});
```

but it blinks by crossing from one div to another.

I think, I can use timeouts, but is there a better way? Thx!

Comment: Solved.

I've just had to use mouseleave instead of mouseout. It works with position:absolute if nested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're using this for a nav submenu or something similar.

I would suggest nesting .otherclass within .someclass.

Comment: yes, it's about submenu, but the second div has position:absolute, so the first's div dimensions does not change, when second div fades in...

Answer (score 1):

Can you wrap the two DIVs in another element and put the hover function on that outer element. That should cover the time when you are between the two.

Answer (score 1):

put 'otherclass' into 'someclass' and set in someclass min-height:200px;

```
<div class="someclass">
 <div>Some text</div>
 <div class="otherclass">text</div>
</div>
```